# Install Progressive Web App as an App through the App Store

Tags: cordova, phonegap, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App (build with wordpress) and I want to upload this App to the App Store. I know phonegap/cordova but I don't know how and if it is possible to display the remote web app in full screen in such an app.

What is the best way to build such an app? Is it possible or do I have to build a new local website for the app?

And is it allowed to upload an app to the App Store, which "only" show a remote website?

Answer (score 1):

Deploying a PWA through the app store is completely missing the point of a PWA. It's intention is to be easily installed through a webbrowser.
It *is* possible to deploy one, if you absolutely must, but you cannot simply point to your webpage and say "deploy this". You need to build a Cordova app, or something similar, to generate a proper Android or iOS app.
Luckily there is a tool that can help: [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com) can help you generate apps for several platforms, including Android, iOS, and others. Note that these are not finished, and you may need to tweak several things before you can get it up and running.

However, it is my sincere opinion that deploying a PWA like this is unnecessary and missing the benefits of a PWA. Its main feature is that it is, at its root, nothing more than a HTML5 page with some extra features. One of those features is the ease of installing. If you deploy the app in an app store, you miss out on that feature.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. The problem is the usability. A lot of people know how to handle the App Store but installing through a webbrowser is to much, also the benefit of Push Notifications and other stuff is missing with a PWA.

Comment: Push notifications are supported, but are indeed limited. If notifications are a must-have, a PWA is not something you should look into.